# Detect strings containing only digits, letters and one or more question marks

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I am writing a python regex that matches only string that consists of letters, digits and one or more question marks.

For example, `regex1: ^[A-Za-z0-9?]+$` returns strings with or without `?`

I want a regex2 that matches expressions such as `ABC123?A, 1AB?CA?, ?2ABCD, ???, 123?` but not `ABC123, ABC.?1D1, ABC(a)?1d`
on mysql, I did that and it works:

```
select *
from (
select * from norm_prod.skill_patterns
where pattern REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9?]+$') AS XXX
where XXX.pattern not REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

Comment: It's still not clear what types of string you want to match. Sample inputs are great, but also please give a description of why those strings should/n't be matched

Comment: Is `?` a valid string? Is `123?34?` a valid string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sure

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for your comment. the string should include only `?` as a special characters 1 or more times as I mentioned . Let me know what you want me to edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
^(?=.*\?)[a-zA-Z0-9\?]+$
```

[**As you can see here at regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BO0M4R/1)

## Explanation

The `(?=.*\?)` is a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that tells the regex that the start of the match should be followed by 0 or more characters and then a `?` - i.e., there should be a `?` somewhere in the match.
The `[a-zA-Z0-9\?]+` matches one-or-more occurrences of the characters given in the character class i.e. `a-z`, `A-Z` and digits from `0-9`, and the question mark `?`.

Altogether, the regex first checks if there is a question mark somewhere in the string to be matched. If yes, then it matches the characters mentioned above. If either the `?` is not present, or there is some foreign character, then the string is not matched.

Comment: I think you don't need to escape `?` inside the bracket. we only escape these 4 chars `^, -, ], \`

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I usually escape everything inside it just to be safe and to make it a bit more readable. But yeah, it doesn't need to be escaped inside character classes.

Comment: @LearnToGrow This solution marks a single `?` as valid. Is that desired? https://regex101.com/r/C8Kh4l/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518160/detect-string-with-integer-characters-and-question-mark/72518508#comment128103503_72518160).

Comment: @Robo, can you add the `[a-zA-Z0-9\?]+$` in your explanantion

Comment: @RoboMop thnx. just because `.*` can match any specific characters but you added `[a-zA-Z0-9\?]+` to exclude the rest of specific characters such `., ), etc`

Comment: Yep that's correct :)

Comment: @RoboMop can you test it on mysql `https://www.regextester.com/112633`

Comment: You'll need to use the 'g' and 'm' flags for it to work that way. `g` matches globally, meaning you get multiple matches. `m` matches multiline, so `^` and `$` match the start and end of the lines respectively. You can click on "flags" and then enable `g` and `m` to get it working like in the demo I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You can validate an alphanumeric string with one or more question marks using

```sql
where pattern REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]*([?][A-Za-z0-9]*)+$'
```

In Python:

```py
re.search(r'^[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:\?[A-Za-z0-9]*)+$', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B61mAt/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` - zero or more letters or digits
- `([?][A-Za-z0-9]*)+` - one or more repetitions of a `?` char and then zero or more letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

If you plan to apply this to any Unicode string, consider using POSIX character classes:

```sql
where pattern REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]*([?][[:alnum:]]*)+$'
```

where `[[:alnum:]]` matches any letters and digits. In Python:

```py
re.search(r'^[^\W_]*(?:\?[^\W_]*)+$', text)
```

In Python, all shorthand character classes are Unicode aware by default, and the `[^\W_]` pattern is a `\w` (that matches letters, digits, connector punctuation) with `_` subtracted from it.

Answer (score 2):

If there should be at least a single question mark present using MySQL or Python:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*\?[A-Za-z0-9?]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` Match optional chars A-Z a-z 0-9
- `\?` Match a question mark
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` Match optional chars A-Z a-z 0-9 or ?
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HFp23O/1).

In MySQL double escape the backslash like:

```
REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]*\\?[A-Za-z0-9?]*$'
```